# Reading the GetReservationRQ xml

Tags: sabre

Working on a SABRE webapp for our company. I'm a complete beginner and I've made the SOAP call to get back GetReservationRQ.
No problem.
Physically I can see and read the xml.
What's the best practice approach to reading through the xml and getting it into practical use within state.
I would prefer to convert it to json and work with it there, but that appears to be very little I can comprehend about converting it.
What techniques do you use?
Example: I want to grab the for grab the stl19:AccountingLines element and the child nodes and convert those to json...
Sorry this is a basic question... but nothing is easy when you're starting out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the XML schema from the developer studio and use some tool to convert the schemat to class files (this depends on your programming language). Once you have the classes then you can serialize/deserialize XML to object and vice versa.
If your language doesn't have this type of support, you can use XPATH to read the XML and parse the message.

Example:

```
node = xmlRQ.SelectSingleNode("//soap:Body/a:DebitPointsRQ/a:LoyaltyMembershipID", nsmgr);
            if (node != null && node.InnerText != string.Empty)
                _debitRequest.LoyaltyMembershipID =node.InnerText;
```

Comment: What is the programming language you are using?

Comment: Typescript ...
I have managed to find a way..but I don't think it's that elegant. 
I have reached out to the vendor of the tool to ask for a best practice version as everything developing a plug-in to this app will likely encounter the same as me...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you look at https://github.com/highsource/jsonix.  This would allow you to compile the xsd files that define the request and response messages for the GetReservationRQ web service into javascript files you can use within your typescript project.  This would be one of the most elegant solutions for dealing with xml <-> json conversion.

Comment: Thanks @httPants. Unfortunately our project/vendor doesn't allow 3rd party tools. It's native js or whatever tools they allow now and that's it.